# Where can I find a Simple Hello World example for Ubuntu SDK (QT)?

Tags: application-development, qt, c++, c

I've been trying to get a simple window with button.
And i have no idea on how to "bind" a button from the QML thing to a C/C++ function for example.

I followed the example from [developer.ubuntu.com](http://developer.ubuntu.com) but it didn't involve what I am trying to do.

Can someone give me a example of how to do this?
Or hint me to some documentation on how to do this,i haven't been able to find anything so far.

Comment: See if [this](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/programming-languages/qml/) or [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmlevents.html) helps. Qt uses signals/slots to bind actions to events. QML may work the same way.

Comment: Please post what you found as an answer to your own question then, it will help other people who are asking the same thing

Comment: Will do that as soon as the  8 hours min. wait time is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what i needed on [Official Documentacion for QT5](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/) which matched the version i was using ( which was the problem the whole time ).

Looks like the guide i followed from [developer.ubuntu.com](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) told me to install QT5 IDE
and i had been reading 4.X documentacion.